# Outline to Multigeometry on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

Is it possible to style the outline of the total multigeometry area in KML?

LineStyle seems to outline all the invidual polygons inside MultiGeometry, but I would like to draw only outline of the multigeometry area.

[image]

Here's the KML in question:

```
<Placemark> 
    <Style Id="style32312"> 
         <PolyStyle> 
           <color>40e87649</color>
         </PolyStyle> 
         <LineStyle>
            <color>7da00000</color>
            <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>

    </Style> 
    <styleUrl>#style32312</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry>
        <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>22.634252,62.300871 22.591748,62.311126 22.531777,62.220705 22.524829,62.210193 22.505328,62.213479 22.450427,62.198459 22.373688,62.142448 22.320064,62.103106 22.198722,62.103336 22.175338,62.152407 21.949961,62.250374 21.938981,62.260434 21.868986,62.324796 21.875631,62.361897 21.985902,62.465844 22.004909,62.512543 22.009583,62.524311 22.012226,62.532525 22.013208,62.537043 22.041524,62.541445 22.127802,62.527125 22.141883,62.550843 22.292023,62.531849 22.29585,62.523556 22.3688,62.507323 22.364156,62.492548 22.429879,62.482091 22.48777,62.478511 22.544945,62.466216 22.5814,62.467665 22.600695,62.441395 22.641898,62.411719 22.634604,62.361992 22.663263,62.317459 22.634252,62.300871</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>22.373688,62.142448 22.450427,62.198459 22.505328,62.213479 22.524829,62.210193 22.531777,62.220705 22.591748,62.311126 22.634252,62.300871 22.745575,62.27331 22.831252,62.270884 22.834447,62.25625 22.83992,62.23907 22.842269,62.236846 22.845478,62.213326 22.84606,62.209051 22.846397,62.20658 22.847731,62.196783 22.841453,62.186866 22.861626,62.172556 22.833476,62.162983 22.830632,62.162015 22.823097,62.1613 22.819407,62.165687 22.770894,62.154395 22.764333,62.141644 22.78024,62.060724 22.695866,62.050857 22.683771,62.053693 22.670488,62.051006 22.602102,62.037082 22.564049,62.010731 22.539295,62.000753 22.522595,61.998106 22.507282,62.000051 22.510815,62.011722 22.438134,62.00738 22.433172,62.013213 22.428243,62.022591 22.412975,62.02084 22.384701,62.01765 22.377735,62.028373 22.42298,62.030498 22.449847,62.031753 22.44402,62.035588 22.435431,62.041221 22.420453,62.051041 22.41114,62.085811 22.426379,62.092423 22.445412,62.109543 22.42942,62.109757 22.416405,62.126876 22.401532,62.124701 22.387075,62.138789 22.373688,62.142448</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>22.041524,62.541445 22.063128,62.544815 22.111375,62.563724 22.111132,62.597708 22.099622,62.605416 22.038034,62.607155 22.018165,62.60771 21.993183,62.616539 21.969522,62.623302 21.942359,62.615298 21.937137,62.601586 21.935965,62.586809 21.90417,62.588771 21.90449,62.598124 21.903001,62.60376 21.886352,62.608618 21.87755,62.606953 21.868042,62.599148 21.806142,62.601696 21.799399,62.594268 21.781885,62.596921 21.812555,62.614631 21.81842,62.624133 21.808718,62.629651 21.790088,62.617744 21.782547,62.615561 21.76985,62.611882 21.75765,62.614757 21.755676,62.6243 21.723553,62.629863 21.721917,62.618266 21.705812,62.6113 21.675179,62.615336 21.671799,62.60883 21.656806,62.612939 21.667088,62.621385 21.699496,62.620556 21.704331,62.631886 21.702685,62.635202 21.662245,62.640045 21.698746,62.654819 21.706729,62.658047 21.727243,62.666336 21.750199,62.676414 21.790968,62.694225 21.747797,62.720203 21.729138,62.767665 21.728774,62.821073 21.765226,62.847604 21.772061,62.863564 21.830963,62.845363 21.8424,62.817563 21.858236,62.811788 21.874386,62.809774 21.914718,62.799709 21.958322,62.78994 21.97303,62.787596 22.008832,62.774425 22.063233,62.763454 22.067108,62.768635 22.121068,62.760182 22.124243,62.767324 22.200677,62.751574 22.167178,62.733829 22.150152,62.719577 22.305663,62.687971 22.316324,62.692345 22.392485,62.679288 22.415289,62.67182 22.43403,62.665677 22.508343,62.629996 22.520749,62.6287 22.522007,62.628568 22.535151,62.627194 22.546767,62.629085 22.569197,62.619352 22.584673,62.626841 22.609686,62.628929 22.63745,62.618275 22.623504,62.602989 22.664777,62.603371 22.665259,62.599855 22.641075,62.565217 22.628018,62.561087 22.609293,62.568074 22.599927,62.568058 22.557674,62.527076 22.523015,62.522546 22.529986,62.496221 22.576643,62.474901 22.5814,62.467665 22.544945,62.466216 22.48777,62.478511 22.429879,62.482091 22.364156,62.492548 22.3688,62.507323 22.29585,62.523556 22.292023,62.531849 22.141883,62.550843 22.127802,62.527125 22.041524,62.541445</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>


    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: Could you include a picture of what it is you are trying to accomplish? If I have interpreted it right, if you have a polygon within another polygon, you only want to view the outline of the outside polygon?

Comment: I have MultiGeometry that contains multiple polygons. In this case they are counties on a map. 

I would like to outline these counties total area outer border, not every invidual countie border. Ie. not show borders inside the total area, only the outer rim.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done--but it's not the prettiest solution. Because the polygons share borders, it can't really be done (for example, there is no way to display a border for all borders of Polygon1 except for the southern border). There will need to be an additional shape created for the "master" polygon.

You can create a new layer of KML polygons where all of the multi-part polygons are dissolved into one (every software has a different way of doing this, doing a simple google or stack exchange search on 'dissolve' and whatever GIS or editing software you use will get you results). Create a solid line border and transparent center on the border [(see my answer here for formatting KML transparency)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173826/how-to-create-translucent-objects-in-kml/173834#173834) while creating a fill color without a border for the inner, multipart polygons.